# Horizontal scrolling to the end with ScrollViewer XAML wp8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer, horizontal-scrolling

I have a ScrollViewer in my XAML. I want to scroll it horizontally to the end of right side so that user can see all the controls in ScrollViewer.

Here's my code:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollFilter" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecAntiqueFilter" Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100" DoubleTapped="RecAntiqueFilter_DoubleTapped" Tapped="RecAntiqueFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecBlurFilter" Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-200,0" Tapped="RecBlurFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecHSTFilter" Fill="Blue" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-400,0" Tapped="RecHSTFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecBFilter" Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-600,0" Tapped="RecBlurFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecHFilter" Fill="Blue" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-800,0" Tapped="RecHSTFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecFilter" Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-1000,0" Tapped="RecBlurFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecHcFilter" Fill="Yellow" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-1200,0" Tapped="RecHSTFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecFake" Fill="Transparent" Height="100" Width="400" Margin="0,-100,-1400,0"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For horizontal scroll, you must use stack panel **orientation** property, Updated code is in the following.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollFilter" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecAntiqueFilter" Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100" DoubleTapped="RecAntiqueFilter_DoubleTapped" Tapped="RecAntiqueFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecBlurFilter" Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-200,0" Tapped="RecBlurFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecHSTFilter" Fill="Blue" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-400,0" Tapped="RecHSTFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecBFilter" Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-600,0" Tapped="RecBlurFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecHFilter" Fill="Blue" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-800,0" Tapped="RecHSTFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecFilter" Fill="Green" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-1000,0" Tapped="RecBlurFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecHcFilter" Fill="Yellow" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,-100,-1200,0" Tapped="RecHSTFilter_Tapped"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RecFake" Fill="Transparent" Height="100" Width="400" Margin="0,-100,-1400,0"/>
</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Wow! You just saved my day. Thanks for helping. I was trying to do that since last night. Btw, is there anyway I can modify Horizontal ScrollBar? For example, changing the color of the scrollbar or changing the width of it?

Comment: You're welcome ;) For change styles, you can check MSDN page; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278076(v=vs.95).aspx ... I didn't try this before.